# Fitting arrays into RAM algorithm question

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms

> We'll consider the RAM as a sequence of cells that can contain data. Some cells already contain some data, some are empty. The empty cells form the so-called memory clusters. Thus, a memory cluster is a sequence of some consecutive empty memory cells.
>
> You have exactly $n$ memory clusters, the $i$-th cluster consists of $a_i$ cells. You need to find memory for m arrays in your program. The $j$-th array takes $2^{b_j}$ consecutive memory cells. There possibly isn't enough memory for all m arrays, so your task is to determine what maximum number of arrays can be located in the available memory clusters. Of course, the arrays cannot be divided between the memory clusters. Also, no cell can belong to two arrays.
>
> Input
> The first line of the input contains two integers $n$ and $m$ ($1 \le n$, $m \le 10^6$). The next line contains $n$ integers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ ($1 \le a_i \le 10^9$). The next line contains m integers $b_1, b_2, ..., b_m$ ($1 \le 2^{b_i} \le 10^9$).
>
> Output
> Print a single integer — the answer to the problem.

I cannot understand the solution to this question from Codeforces, https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/7749. Why are they considering arrays of size 1? The arrays could be any size? Why do we need to consider odd or even. To be honest, I dont understand this solution at all.

Answer (score 1):

> The $j$-th array takes $2^{b_j}$ consecutive memory cells.

Suppose $j=4$ and $b_4=0$. That means the $4$-th array takes $2^{b_4}=2^0=1$ consecutive memory cell.

In case it is surprising to you that $2^0=1$, you can understand it as, for example, $1=\frac{2^3}{2^3}=2^{3-3}=2^0$.

Does the word "cells", which is in plural form, require $2^{b_j}$ be greater than 1? Not necessarily, although "$2^{b_j}$ consecutive memory cell(s)" could have been clearer. It is very common to use the plural form of a word to refer a group/collection of unknown or variable quantities using the plural form, especially in math and computer science.

**Exercise**: Understand that $3^0=1$. Understand that $a^0=1$ for any nonzero number $a$.